# 2FA login on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: security, ubuntu, authentication, google-authenticator

I am trying to implement 2FA for logins on my ubuntu machine to increase security alongside with an encrypted home folder. I've opted to use the google authenticator pam module as this also works offline. I've followed the documentation on google's GitHub repository https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/blob/f2db05c52884e4d6c3894f5fd2cf10f0f686aec2/libpam/README.md but it seems to me that you can easily by-pass the MFA as:

- the settings are saved in a .google_authenticator file
- the settings file contains your secret key that you can use to add the account to the google authenticator app to receive OTP tokens
- the .google_authenticator file must sit outside of your encrypted folder as otherwise you can't login
- therefore if you boot directly into a root shell (recovery). You can get the secret key from the file and thus bypass the second factor.

Therefore I have the following questions:

- am I missing something in the google authenticator set-up?
- are there any other solutions that would work offline and can not be so easily bypassed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> therefore if you boot directly into a root shell (recovery)

There is a reason for that, and the reason is as you mentioned above -> recovery.
So, you are not missing anything, except the scope of 2FA: yes it can be bypassed if you have direct access to the server, but it secures remote access (SSH) perfectly fine. Unfortunately there is no way to disallow that.